# Spring Security WebSecurityConfig Ignore certain requests with multiple conditions

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to bypass all the filters and security layers by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class and implementing `configure(WebSecurity web)` method.

It works perfectly if I want to have multiple endpoints to be ignored. It works as well if I wanted to ignore either requests with a specific endpoint or having certain request header, but it does not work satisfying two conditions, meaning ignoring a request with certain path and certain request header. It basically ignores if either of those conditions are met. I have tried different variations like:

```java
RequestHeaderRequestMatcher requestHeaderRequestMatcher = new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(HEADER_HEALTH_CHECK, "1");
AntPathRequestMatcher antPathRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/healthStats");
web
    .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(requestHeaderRequestMatcher, antPathRequestMatcher);

web
    .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(requestHeaderRequestMatcher)
        .antMatchers("/healthStats");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine the two request matchers, see [`AndRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AndRequestMatcher.html):

> `RequestMatcher` that will return true if all of the passed in `RequestMatcher` instances match.

Your modified configuration:

```java
RequestHeaderRequestMatcher requestHeaderRequestMatcher = new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(HEADER_HEALTH_CHECK, "1");
AntPathRequestMatcher antPathRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/healthStats");
AndRequestMatcher andRequestMatcher = new AndRequestMatcher(requestHeaderRequestMatcher, antPathRequestMatcher);
web
    .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(andRequestMatcher);
```