# Spring Boot Security Disable Web security for specific URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am using Spring security for a Spring Boot application containing a set of Restful services. I have enabled Web security with basic authentication.
I would like to have basic authentication enabled except for specific API URL ending with a certain pattern. (For example, a healthcheck API like: /application/_healthcheck)

Code looks like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Value("${application.security.authentication.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${application.security.authentication.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(username).password(password).roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("*/_healthcheck");
    }
}
```

However, whenever I invoke the .../application/_healthcheck URL, browser always prompts me to enter credentials.

Alternately, I even tried ignoring this path from Spring boot's application.properties (removed the configure method with web.ignoring().antMatchers("*/_healthcheck")) but still can't get rid of authentication for this endpoint

```
security.ignored=/_healthcheck,*/_healthcheck
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security WebSecurityConfig Ignore certain requests with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814064/spring-security-websecurityconfig-ignore-certain-requests-with-multiple-conditio)

Comment: Thanks @dur but I added the property configuration only after web.ignoring().antMatchers("*/_healthcheck") didn't work. Removing that configure method and keeping only property configuration also didn't help.

Comment: `web.ignoring().antMatchers("*/_healthcheck") ` is wrong, because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43711163/5277820.

Comment: Thanks dur, that solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [antMatchers that matches any beginning of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704389/antmatchers-that-matches-any-beginning-of-path)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/application/_healthcheck");
}
```

The difference in above sample and your code is usage of `web` over `http`. Try with web and see if it work { practically it should :) }.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a permission list and use it to disable security.

```
List<String> permitAllEndpointList = Arrays.asList(
            AUTHENTICATION_URL,
            REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
            EXTERNAL_AUTH_URL,
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html"
);
```

and then add this statement to your HttpSecurity object

```
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(permitAllEndpointList.toArray(new String[permitAllEndpointList.size()]))
.permitAll()
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This will skip authentication part for health URL.

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("*/_healthcheck").permitAll() // added this line
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, however as dur mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43711163/5277820, I had to update path pattern as .antMatchers("/**/_healthcheck")